# How to make the footer menu look like main menu on top?

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, footer

I am using a theme called "Venture" and created a child theme to edit the styling via CSS, however I am running into a bit of an issue. The navigation our client wants to use is available on top as part of the theme, as the main nav, but the footer menu/nav is a different styling altogether and seems to be wrapped by a PHP function or a widget, I can't really tell.

I want to to make it look like the one on top. However, no matter what I do in CSS it won't change, and I find that by adding more CSS code which is essentially already in the parent theme is redundant and unnecessary, since I can use them if coded correctly. How to solve this issue?

The site I am building is on a sub-domain on WP.

Comment: some code and maybe some screen shots would help.

Comment: Please be more specific? I am not sure which code to show you? Basically I want the primary menu styling/look on the top to be same as the bottom. The theme I am using is called "Venture"... I am making child themes to control the CSS but as you can see above in my original post. However I am going through hell trying to figure this out... So much easier to code from scratch. smh...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out a great way to do this. Basically I created a footer.php file and added it to my child theme folder. I copied the code from the parent "footer.php" file and pasted to the Child version. Then I removed the guts of the menu where it inside of the  It used to point to secondary menu, now it points to primary. Then I followed it up by styling with CSS. I renamed menu to menu_2 as follows:

```
              <div class="menu_2">
        <?php if (has_nav_menu( 'primary' )) {
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'container' => 'menu',
                'container_class' => '',
                'menu_class' => 'dropdown',
                'menu_id' => 'mainmenu',
                'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                'theme_location' => 'primary'
                ));
        } else {
            echo '<p>Please set your Main navigation menu on the <strong><a href="'.get_admin_url().'nav-menus.php">Appearance > Menus</a></strong> page.</p>';
        } ?>
    </div>
```